# c# WebView2 user directory "Access Denied"

Tags: c#, webview2

I am having issues with the .NET WebView2 control. I thought I had it fixed but it is not working. I have read numerous posts to no avail.

I have a WPF C# application that runs on a server. Various people log into the server via a web browser and run the app.

Within this app, I open up a WebView2 browser, setting the user data directory to a unique directory for each person.

When I set the user data directory and call EnsureCoreWebView2Async(), I get an error in the exception code "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Below is the code:

```
public static async void InitializeWebView(WebView2 browser, string path)
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

   browser.CreationProperties = new CoreWebView2CreationProperties()
   {
      UserDataFolder = path
   };

   try
   {
      await browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
   }
   catch( Exception ex)
   {
      Log.LogString("Ensure error: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

I have tried various things without success. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by: _Various people log into the server via a web browser and run the app._ Also, it's not clear what value you're using for "Path". The error message is quite clear, you don't have permission to create the userdatafolder in the location that you're attempting to create it in.

Comment: A single app on a server that multiple people run. People access the app by logging into it. Part of the app displays a WebView2 control. I set the browser files to a directory unique for each person. For instance, c:\files\person1; c:\files\person2; etc. Regarding your last statement, that is incorrect. The CreateDirectory method works just fine, adding the directory. The browser though, cannot write to it. Therein lies the problem (with the error generated).

Comment: You should create a folder in the `App_Data Local` folder with your company name and use that. Then the user will have access to it

Comment: Thank you user9938. Using the link and comments you provided, I have the following code:

         CoreWebView2Environment webview;
         webview = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, path, null);

         try
         {
            await browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webview);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            TSFLog.LogString("Ensure error: " + ex.Message);
         }

The path is my t:\somedir\person1 directory. I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Regarding Poul's suggestion, I changed the directory to c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\person1 and that did not work either. The directory was created but the call to EnsureCoreWebView2Async generated the same exception as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: user9938, sorry for the poor code formatting. I was trying to learn how to format it, but I couldn't since I ran over the 5-minute time limit on comments.

Comment: About formatting: Surround code with back-ticks (``) to get `code`.

Comment: Try to right-click the folder and select 'Properties', 'Security', then inspect the permissions.

Comment: if you are still stuck after all the other advice use sysinternals procmon, you can see all teh file IO that you server if performing, plus all the return codes, you will see what file is being accessed and failing

Answer (score 3):

I'm not all that familiar with [CoreWebView2CreationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.corewebview2creationproperties?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44), but according to the documentation.

> Its main purpose is to be set to CreationProperties in order to
> customize the environment used by a WebView2 during **implicit
> initialization**...If you need complete control over the environment used by a WebView2 control then you'll need to initialize the control explicitly by creating your own environment with CreateAsync(String, String, CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions) and passing it to EnsureCoreWebView2Async(CoreWebView2Environment) *before* you set the Source property to anything.

As mentioned in the documentation referenced above, implicit initialization occurs when the `Source` property is set and `CoreWebView2` hasn't been explicitly initialized.

To explicitly initialize `CoreWebView2`, try the following:

```
public async Task InitializeCoreWebView2Async(WebView2 wv, string userDataFolder = null)
{
    //initialize CoreWebView2 

    CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = null;
    CoreWebView2Environment cwv2Environment = null;

    //it's recommended to create the userDataFolder in the same location
    //that your other application data is stored (ie: in a folder in %APPDATA%)
    //if not specified, we'll create a folder in %TEMP%
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userDataFolder))
        userDataFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

    //create WebView2 Environment using the installed or specified WebView2 Runtime version.
    //cwv2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\1.0.1054.31", userDataFolder, options);
    cwv2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, userDataFolder, options);

    //initialize
    await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(cwv2Environment);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UserDataFolder: " + userDataFolder);
}
```

**Note**: If one desires to explicitly initialize `CoreWebView2`, it must be done prior to setting the `Source` property for the `WebView2` control.

**Usage**:

```
await InitializeCoreWebView2Async(webView21, Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name));
```

**Resources**:

- [CoreWebView2 Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44)
- [CoreWebView2CreationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.corewebview2creationproperties?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44)
- [CoreWebView2Environment Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environment?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44)
- [CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environment.createasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44)
- [WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(CoreWebView2Environment) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44)

Comment: I have tried what you have above using various paths, including the one in your suggest (the temp dir), all to no available; I have different drives, different paths, and nothing works; I still get Access is denied. I also created the dir to see if that made a diff. I do not know why my app can create directories but WebView2 cannot use them.

I also tested removing the WebView2 control from my XAML and create it instead, then calling CreateAsync(null, path), then EnsureCoreWebView2Async with the environment and it errors every time.

Comment: There must be something fundamental that I am doing wrong. I have even tested running the app under the administrator profile, which made no difference.

Comment: Lastly, the app using any directory works just find on my local computer. It is when I copy it up to my Azure server that I am having these issues.

Comment: Update your post with the new code that you're using. Also add the method where you call the initialization code. Common reasons for it not working are 1) setting the WebView2 control Source property prior to explicitly initializing CoreWebView2 2) order of execution - not `await`ing the `Task` completion. Log messages at various points: 1) Prior to calling the initialization code 2) after the call to the initialization code

Comment: 2) subscribe to [CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.corewebview2initializationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44) and log a message here. Also check the version of MS Edge being used by calling: [CoreWebView2Environment.GetAvailableBrowserVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environment.getavailablebrowserversionstring?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44)

Comment: If you're using Azure, you should add that information to your OP - perhaps in the tag.

Comment: Due to comment character limitations, I have posted a response to user9938 in the Answer section.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but I ran into the same problem...and found a simple solution from
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7190 ... set the environment variable used by the webview before you create it.

```
        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "AppName");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER", path);

        InitializeComponent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your continued help. Due to character limitations, I am responding to your questions in an Answer section. In response to your comments...

If the Source was being set prior to initialization, I would be getting a different error (which I have had in the past).

Here is the xaml for the WebView2 control:

```
<Wpf:WebView2 Name="Browser" Margin="20,20,20,20" CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted="Browser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted" />
```

As you can see, I am subscribed to the InitializationComplete event, which is not being called due to the error.

Here is the source for the form that hosts the WebView2 control:

```
private async void _DoIt()
{
   try
   {
      var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, Global._GetServerDataDirectory(_Person));
      await Browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
   }
   catch( Exception ex)
   {
      Log.LogString("DoIt error: " + ex.Message);
   }
}

public PayPal(Person person)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   _Person = person;

   _DoIt();

   Log.LogString("After PayPal constructor");
}
```

It is erroring in _DoIt().

Comment: As part of the error message in _DoIt(), I am outputting the version. Here is the text: DoIt error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)); Browser: 98.0.1108.56

Comment: Log the value of `Global._GetServerDataDirectory(_Person)` before using it in `CreateAsync`.

Comment: The method _GetServerDataDirectory() builds a data path and creates the directory if it does not exist. I have also tested replacing this call with a hard-coded path.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after many hours of trying to track this down, the end issue is that Thinfinity's VirtualUI product does not support an application using WebView2. This was my core issue and has been confirmed by the vendor.

Thank you once again for everyone's kind help with this.