# WebView2 Event Handler not working in VB but working in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, postmessage, webview2

Hi i ran into an issue trying to get my C# code running in VB.
Im using a WebView2 and hook to an postMessage event of a Button.

My C# Code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAsync();
        webView.Source = new Uri("SomeApiUri");
    }
    async void InitializeAsync()
    {
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        webView.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += WebMessageRecieved;
        await webView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("window.addEventListener(\'message\', e => { window.chrome.webview.postMessage(e.data); })");
    } 
    void WebMessageRecieved(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
```

With this Code when clicking the Button i get Hello World in the console.

When i use this VB Code:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    InitializeAsync()
    webView.Source = New Uri("SomeApiUri")
End Sub

Private Async Sub InitializeAsync()
    Await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)
    Dim p As CoreWebView2 = webView.CoreWebView2
    AddHandler p.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf WebMessageReceived
    Await webView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("window.addEventListener(\'message\', e => { window.chrome.webview.postMessage(e.data); })")
End Sub

Private Sub WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs) 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
End Sub
```

The Event in VB is never Fired. Why? Does Someone know where the Issue is? Im new to VB and cant get the Event working.

**EDIT:**

So i have changed my Code like [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)
said. I hope i did it as intended. Sadly its still not working.

Heres my Code

```
Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()
    webView.Source = New Uri("SomeApiUri")
End Sub

Private Async Sub Wpf_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Await InitializeAsync()
End Sub


Private Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task
    Await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)
    
    AddHandler webView.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf WebMessageReceived

End Function

Private Sub CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted() Handles webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted
    webView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("window.addEventListener(\'message\', e => { window.chrome.webview.postMessage(e.data); })")
End Sub

Private Sub WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
End Sub
```

**Edit 2:**

So i got it working now. I did simply convert my C# Code to VB with a Converter.
This is the Result:

```
Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        InitializeAsync()
        Me.webView.Source = New Uri("SomeApiUri")

    End Sub

    Private Async Sub InitializeAsync()

        Await Me.webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)
        AddHandler Me.webView.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf Me.WebMessageRecieved

        Await Me.webView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("window.addEventListener('message', e => { window.chrome.webview.postMessage(e.data); })")
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateOutput(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim uri As String = args.TryGetWebMessageAsString()
        Me.Output.Text = uri
        Me.webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString(uri)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebMessageRecieved(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
    End Sub
```

Somehow this worked i dont know why and how?

Comment: You can write `webView.WebMessageReceived += WebMessageRecieved;` in C# (you don't need the underlying CoreWebView2 object) and the same in VB.Net: `AddHandler webView.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf WbBuildup_WebMessageReceived` -- You should not try to initialize WebView2 from the Constructor of a Window / Form. Subscribe to the `Initialized` or `Loaded` events / override `OnLoad` or use the `Load` handler, marking them `async`. Call `await InitializeAsync();` there. -- `AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync` should be set in the `[WebView2].CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` handler.

Comment: `InitializeAsync()` now returns `Task`, it's not a `void` / `Sub` method (i.e., `Private Async Function InitializeAsync() as Task`). -- Some VB.Net 
 examples here: [Which WebView2 event/function can be use to replace ScriptNotify Webview event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278278/7444103)

Comment: Your're C# code is incorrect, as well. All of the things that @Jimi mentioned also apply to the C# code.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200515/c-sharp-webview2-user-directory-access-denied/71216493#71216493

Comment: As a note, your JavaScript seems to be setting an event handler that reacts to a message posted to the main document using [CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.postwebmessageasjson)

Comment: As previously mentioned, this code is incorrect and introduces a bug into your program. It may or may not work as intended depending on how much time elapses between the time that you call the constructor and the time you attempt to use your instance of the WebView2 control. It will be more apparent if you delete the WebView2 userDataFolder before running your program or debug it to check that the order of execution is as intended.