# webview2: EnsureCoreWebView2Async is called but CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event not triggered after disposing and recreating it

Tags: c#, webview2

I have a browser class in which I have added  webview2 Control.
I have use case where I delete the webview2 browser in my class (check `ShowData` method).

If required again I create a new instance of webview2 in my class (check `InitializeWebBrowser`) and navigate to the page.

This is working fine in the installed application. Loading correctly without any issues.

From application built thru code in local dev first-time webview2 browser is shown.  `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` gets called through constructor and `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` event is triggered and page is getting loaded. After deleting the webview2 instance and creating a new one `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` is called but `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` is not called at all, even if we wait for a long time.

Note: `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` event triggered when webview2.dispose is called with failure status.

Any idea why `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` is not called second time?

```
public MyBrowser()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync();
    }
    
    public async void InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync()
    {
      webBrowser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;      
      await webBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
    }
    
    private void WebBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.IsSuccess)
      {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_sDocumentText)) // m_sDocumentText is Private which contains HTML Content
        {         
          webBrowser.NavigateToString(m_sDocumentText);
          m_sDocumentText = string.Empty;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Log.Error($"WebBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted - CoreWebView2 Initialization failed", e.InitializationException);
      }
    }
    
    public void ShowData(string url)
    {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
      {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);        
        InitializeWebBrowser();               
        webBrowser.Source = uri;                
      }
      else 
      {        
        if (webBrowser != null)
        {          
          webBrowser.Dispose();
          webBrowser = null;
        }
      }
    }
    private void InitializeWebBrowser()
    {
      if (webBrowser == null)
      {        
        webBrowser = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        webBrowser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
        webBrowser.Name = "webBrowser";
        webBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
        webBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
        Controls.Clear();
        Controls.Add(this.webBrowser);
        InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync();
      }
    }
    
    
     public void SetDocumentText(string docText)
    {      
      InitializeWebBrowser();
      if (webBrowser.CoreWebView2 != null)
        webBrowser.NavigateToString(docText);
      else       
        m_sDocumentText = docText;
    }
```

Addition Info :

Basically, WebView2 Control itself is not visible after disposing and creating new instance
I have subscribed to `Webview2 VisibleChanged` event. After calling `EnsureCoreWebView2Async`, `VisibleChanged` event is triggered with `webview2.visible` property having value false. (second time)

[image]

After Initialization, Explicitly called the below method with Visible Property set to true

```
public void ShowWebBrowser()
{       
   if (webBrowser?.Visible == false)
   {       
     webBrowser.Visible = true;
   }          
}
```

But VisibleChanged Event gets triggered with webview2.visible property value false even though it was set to true
[image]

Comment: Might not be relevant, but good coding style: Call `webBrowser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted -= WebBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;` before disposing.

Comment: Also, you are not `await`ing `InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync();`. That means it continues immidiately, which might or might not give problems.

Comment: According to the [WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1150.38): _Unless previous initialization has already failed, calling this method additional times with the same parameter will have no effect (any specified environment is ignored) and return the same Task as the first call..._

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200515/c-sharp-webview2-user-directory-access-denied/71216493#71216493 . I have additional posts on WebView2 that may be helpful as well. Click on my username and in the search box append `webView2`

Comment: @PoulBak agree. Need to unsubscribe the event before dispose.

Comment: @PoulBak It was called in the main thread and do not want to block the call by awaiting InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync. My understanding was like let's fire the call and forget. Later when the CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event is triggered navigate to the URL. Unfortunately event itself is not triggered in the above explained scenario

Comment: Are you sure `string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_sDocumentText)` returns false on second call? You set it to an empty string.

Comment: @PoulBak m_sDocumentText has value in the second call but coreweb2initializationcomplete event gets triggered only after dispose is called… and at that time e.IsSuccess has false value

Comment: That is because you don't `await` your calls. Some code 'moves on' and gives you that behavior - a classic race condition.

Comment: @PoulBak Added some more info to question

Comment: You don't `await` `InitializeWebBrowser();`. This means that `if (webBrowser.CoreWebView2 != null)` will return a totally random value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kinda strange issue it used to happen only on some machines not all.

After making the below change it started to work for me.

The main changes are stopping the Initialization of corewebview2 in the constructor and doing it in the normal method.

Previously changes were like first-time corewebview2 Initialization was done in the constructor and the second time onwards it was happening in the Normal method after creating a new instance.

Change 1: Stopped initialization of CoreWebView2 in Constructor

```
public MyBrowser()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  //InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync(); --> Removed this line
}
```

Change 2: In the below method previously was calling InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync() only when creating new instance now moved outside to call everytime.

```
private void InitializeWebBrowser()
{
  if (webBrowser == null)
  {        
    webBrowser = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
    webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    webBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    webBrowser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
    webBrowser.Name = "webBrowser";
    webBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
    webBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
    Controls.Clear();
    Controls.Add(this.webBrowser);   
//    InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync(); --> Moved outside if condition
  }
  InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync();
}
```

Rest Remained Same:

```
public async void InitializeBrowserCoreWebViewAsync()
{
  if (webBrowser.CoreWebView2 == null)
  {
     webBrowser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;      
     await webBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
  }
}

private void WebBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.IsSuccess)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_sDocumentText)) // m_sDocumentText is Private which contains HTML Content
    {         
      webBrowser.NavigateToString(m_sDocumentText);
      m_sDocumentText = string.Empty;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Log.Error($"WebBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted - CoreWebView2 Initialization failed", e.InitializationException);
  }
}

public void ShowData(string url)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
  {
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);        
    InitializeWebBrowser();               
    webBrowser.Source = uri;                
  }
  else 
  {        
    if (webBrowser != null)
    {          
      webBrowser.Dispose();
      webBrowser = null;
    }
  }
}

public void SetDocumentText(string docText)
{      
  InitializeWebBrowser();
  if (webBrowser.CoreWebView2 != null)
    webBrowser.NavigateToString(docText);
  else       
    m_sDocumentText = docText;
}
```