# Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 not loading view for second copy of the same application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple desktop application which loads **.cshtml** view in a windows form. I build it and published on my remote machine for a specific folder on drive D. Everything works fine, if only 1 user from this machine runs the instance of this application on a target path. But if any other user try to run the same app, while the copy of that app is already running by another user it sees a blank form instead.

I've already covered the code with some logging and **try{} catch{}** blocks, but have no interesting info so far. The service which returns the desktop view runs at the same intranet and it returns the result all the time if you just go to URL against the browser.

What could be the problem and how can I find the true cause of its appearance?

I will be grateful for any advice.

**Update 1**: ***CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted** contains an exception -> The requested resource is in use. (0x800700AA)*

```
     #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
            this.webView = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.webView)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // webView
            // 
            this.webView.AllowExternalDrop = false;
            this.webView.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.webView.CreationProperties = null;
            this.webView.DefaultBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.webView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
            this.webView.Name = "webView";
            this.webView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(690, 125);
            this.webView.TabIndex = 0;
            this.webView.ZoomFactor = 1D;
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.AccessibleDescription = "MessageBoard Wrapper";
            this.AccessibleName = "MessageBoard Wrapper";
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(710, 145);
            this.Controls.Add(this.webView);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 100);
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Text = "MessageBoard Wrapper";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.webView)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

       private HttpClient GetClient()
       {
         var result = new HttpClient();
         return result;
       }

        private Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 webView;

        private string _baseUrl = "here I have my service url";

    public MainForm()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            var client = GetClient();
                try
                {
                    var targetmUrlForCustomBusinessLogic = "url address here";
                    var response = client.GetAsync(targetmUrlForCustomBusinessLogic).Result;

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var t = Task.Run(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;

                     //here I have some code too

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var message = ex.Message;
                    //TODO: add logging here
                  
                }
                finally
                {
                    client.Dispose();
                }

            webView.Source = new Uri(_baseUrl);

            webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;

            ResizeEnd += (object sender, EventArgs e) => SaveFormSettings();
            Move += (object sender, EventArgs e) => SaveFormSettings();
            Shown += (object sender, EventArgs e) => LoadFormSettings();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: .Net Core 3.1 ?! Move to .Net 6 -- You're not initializing the WebView2 Control

Comment: We will move to .Net 6 definitely. The component initialization is going inside of   InitializeComponent() method. As I told at the description all works well, if 1 copy of the app running at the same time. @Jimi

Comment: You cannot initialize a WebView2 control in `InitializeComponent()`, it uses async methods tat you need to await. Whatever you're doing, in relation to this Control, you have to show it here

Comment: I've updated the post to provide more details, including the autogenerated code for InitializeComponent() method. @Jimi

Comment: You're setting up some base properties in `InitializeComponent()`, I'm referring to the async method that calls `await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(...)` and `await [WebView2 Instance].EnsureCoreWebView2Async(...)` etc. (i.e., the initialization procedure)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216493/10024425, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66501901/10024425.

Comment: I don't use either CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync() or EnsureCoreWebView2Async() in the app. Sorry, I'm a web developer, don't have much experience with desktop apps.  @Jimi.

Comment: The following may also be helpful: [Manage user data folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder?tabs=dotnet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this application to work in multi user mode by making the following changes.

1. I removed initialization of `webView.Source` property
2. I added a method which is preparing the environment for each user and explicitly trigger the initialization of webView control. (I'm calling this method inside of MainForm

   `private async Task InitAsync(string path) { var env = await Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(userDataFolder: path); await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);`
   }
3. I set up **path** param for the user data folder in a next way

`path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{Environment.UserName}");`

4. I binded navigation path to the target URL in against CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event handler.

   `private void webView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e) { if (webView != null && webView.CoreWebView2 != null) { webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(_baseUrl); } }`

All the steps above solved my issus, which was occuring because each new instance of the app for a new user requred environment folder to deal with `webView` component. Hope that will save some time for somebody.

Comment: Much thanks.  For me, I added the path creation and call to InitAsync in form Load.  There is no need to return a Task from InitAsync as the await is done within the function, so void is fine.  I also did not need to hook the InitializationCompleted event.  Configuring the webView prior to assignment of the Source is all that is required.  I suppose the webView Source should not be assigned within the designer, but only after call to InitAsync on form load.